# Is it possible to change the language displayed on UIResponderStandardEditActions when using UITextView?

Tags: uitextview, uimenucontroller

I have searched on google and checked many pages, it seems nobody faced such a problem, and I also checked Apple's documents, no topics or properties can be set.

The device language is also in Chinese, but the standard actions are still in English, but I want the menu titles are showing as device language.

[image]

Thanks very much in advance!